# Getting information of action that running on the table

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

**hi everybody**
I am learning SSIS for the first time.
i want to make package in ssis to make a copy of table that i'm working on it to another table with understanding when insert,delete or update with their data actually i want the query or something like that with event handler of package in ssis. and what parameter or variable are saving data
here the link can help you if you want 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141788.aspx
i hope there is hero to can help me

Comment: Could you try restating the question?

Comment: i want to write a event handler to sense with one of action like insert,delete or update are execute on table A and do a same query in table B.

Comment: It sounds like you'd like to have SSIS detect when changes happen to a source table and perform the same action in a different database. That's not an SSIS task. That'd be a trigger, service broker, change tracking, change data capture, replication, etc problem domain. SSIS is designed for bulk processing - every N interval we start processing and copy data computing changes. Real-time/event driven is not what SSIS is designed for

Comment: i want to detect the change that from the ssis so cant use sql server service

Comment: You want to use an ETL process for an Event driven process. Courageous, but not wise.

Comment: This is not what SSIS is meant for.  Since you are learning to use it for the first time, why not try first using it for something it was meant to do?

Comment: because my friend ask me to make this package :D

Comment: Then you may tell your friend it is not possible and show him this question and answer if he has any doubts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event handlers in SSIS cannot "sense" the events that take place on your database like inserts, updates and deletes.

Event handlers in SSIS can only sense the events that occur inside the package while it is running.

What you want to do is not possible with SSIS event handlers.

Comment: i want use to detect insert,update or delete command that execute by ssis by event handler

Comment: if i can to understand the query of that will be enough i think